# How to delete Visual Studio and its workloads?

Tags: visual-studio

I have deleted visual studio but space in my local disk doesn't seem to be freed from workloads (such as Winforms, .NET). I wanted to install visual studio 2022 after deleting previous version but looks like I messed up somewhere. Can someone explain how to do that? Or at least is it possible to use workloads of 2019 in 2022?

I tried to delete them in Visual studio installer, even tried to reinstall Visual Studio 2019 so I could reach to the workloads editing but in only suggests me to install them again.

Comment: What makes you think the stuff wasn't cleaned up? And how did you "delete" VS2019? I do hope you used the installer.

Comment: Yep, I uninstalled it through visual studio installer, and what makes me think that it wasn't fully deleted is that local disk size didn't change after that

Comment: What's the disk size of the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019`? This should be mostly empty after an uninstallation. Other folders in the parent folder contain shared components and may be reused again.